# Troubleshooting "Skipping incompatible library" with ld

Tags: ld, mingw32, msys2

I'm trying to compile some C code against a 32-bit DLL file that was provided to me. However, I get the following errors from ld (edited for conciseness) using the MSYS2 MinGW-32 environment:

```
/usr/x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /<some_path>/mtipli.lib when searching for -lmtipli
/usr/x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /<some_path>/mtipli.dll when searching for -lmtipli
/usr/x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /<some_path>/mtipli.lib when searching for -lmtipli
/usr/x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /<some_path>/mtipli.dll when searching for -lmtipli
/usr/x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /<some_path>/mtipli.lib when searching for -lmtipli
/usr/x86_64-pc-msys/bin/ld: cannot find -lmtipli
```

The last time I got these types of error messages was when I was trying to use a 32-bit library in a 64-bit project. But this time I am as sure as I can be that my compiler is 32-bit.

Does anyone know if there's a way I can get more information so that I can troubleshoot this? I tried using `-Wl,--verbose`, but ld's verbose messages didn't have anything helpful in them.

*More details:*

*I actually have three incarnations of MinGW on my computer. The first is the basic 32-bit MinGW compiler that I installed using mingw-get several years ago. I later installed the MSYS2 environment, which came with a 32-bit and a 64-bit MinGW. In other words, I have two 32-bit version of MinGW.*

*I am forced to use the MSYS2 version of the 32-bit MinGW for my project because the basic one doesn't have some headers/libs that I depend on (i.e. stuff I need in addition to the mtipll.dll file shown above). However, if I make a minimal project using only mtipll.dll, the basic MinGW is actually able to compile it, but the MSYS2 MinGW gives me this same error. I am so confused with all these MinGWs floating around!!!*

Comment: Did you set librarypaths to your 32-bit libraries? (`-L`) Is this the right ld?

Comment: Here is the output from `cpp -v`: `LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/9.3.0/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/9.3.0/../../../../lib/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/9.3.0/../../../:/usr/lib/`. But keep in mind that I only have a 32-bit mtipll.dll available in the first place

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the explanation, though I don't have a solution yet.

By using objdump, I discovered that the mtipli.dll has file format `pe-i386`, and so do any executables that I've compiled with the basic MinGW-32. However, all code compiled with the MSYS2 version of MinGW-32 have file format `pe-x86-64`.

I will ask about this in a new Stack Overflow question and post the link in the comments.

Comment: I posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63136443/linking-with-pe-i386-object-file-and-a-pe-x86-64-object-file