# Linking with pe-i386 object file and a pe-x86-64 object file

Tags: ld, portable-executable, mingw32

Because my understanding of this problem is limited, please excuse me if I provide irrelevant details.

### Question

I have two versions of MingGW on my computer, and both are 32-bit. The first one is what I call "basic MinGW", and it's the one I installed using mingw-get several years ago. The other one came with MSYS2.

Here are the constraints I am dealing with, details provided in the postscript:

- My program depends on library A, which I can only compile from source using the MSYS2 MinGW.
- My program depends on B.dll, a file that was provided to me. I do not have the source.
- Using `objdump`, I discovered that B.dll has file format `pe-i386`
- Using `objdump`, I discovered that programs compiled with the basic MinGW have file format `pe-i386`
- Using `objdump`, I discovered that programs compiled with the MSYS2 MinGW have file format `pe-x86-64`

The end result is this:

- My program cannot compile with the basic MinGW because library A (which must be compiled with MSYS2 MinGW) is incompatible
- My program cannot compile with the MSYS2 MinGW because B.dll is incompatible

What is the difference between these two file formats? If they are both 32-bit, why can't I compile them together? Is it possible to convert B.dll to be compatible with the MSYS2 MinGW?

### Details

- Library A is libevent. At some point, libevent requires `netioapi.h` which does not appear to be present in the basic MinGW. However, MSYS2 MinGW is able to compile libevent.
- B.dll is provided to me in Modelsim. It is the library you must link against fro compiling Verilog PLI programs.

Comment: Okay so for some reason it didn't occur to me that `x86-64` is actually 64 bit. I have no idea why the MSYS2 ships with a compiler called MinGW32 that doesn't actually generate 32-bit executables... so now I just need to figure out how to get it to do that?

Comment: Compiler itself being 32bit or 64bit is of no importance - it reads texts and spit out texts. `gcc -m32` will compile code for 32bit platform. `gcc -m64` will compile code for 64bit platform